# Assert that a pattern does not exist in an ansible variable?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a task that asserts that several patterns do not exist in a declared variable.

```yaml
- name: "Ensure the image name does not contain dev or rc"
  assert:
    that:
      -  "'*-dev*' not in {{ archived_image_name }}"
      -  "'*-rc*' not in {{ archived_image_name }}"
```

Now my problem is that this variable contains the following output format

```
<registryname>.<domain>.io_image_name_version_tag.tar
```

Resulting in the follow error as Ansible thinks that  is an object.

```
"msg": "The conditional check ''*-rc*' not in '<registryname>.<domain>.io_image_name_version_tag.tar' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('*-rc*' not in <registryname>.<domain>.io_image_name_version_tag.tar): '<registryname>' is undefined",
"_ansible_no_log": false
```

Is there a way to get around this? I tried single quoting the variable but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
    - assert:
        that:
          - archived_image_name is not search('-dev')
          - archived_image_name is not search('-rc')
      vars:
        archived_image_name: '<registryname>.<domain>.io_image_name_version_tag.tar'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: All assertions passed
```

and

```yaml
    - assert:
        that:
          - archived_image_name is not search('-dev')
          - archived_image_name is not search('-rc')
      vars:
        archived_image_name: '<registryname>.<domain>.io_image_name_version-rc.tar'
```

fails

```yaml
  assertion: archived_image_name is not search('-rc')
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed
```